# Can I echo the command string executed by 'execute_process'?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake script that creates a command string and runs it with `execute_process`.  But, some of the parameters are not getting filled in properly.  Is there a way to print the actual command string that is getting executed?

There is a `message` call just above it which shows what the command should be but when I run that string on the command line, it works fine while the CMake `execute_process` fails.

Comment: Could it be that you don't set properly the working directory when you run `execute_process`? The error message would help probably.

Comment: Enable the verbose mode of CMake and just `echo` the parameters inside your script that's executed in `execute_process`? Or maybe echo that to a file?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from CMake 3.15, [`execute_process` has a `COMMAND_ECHO <where>` parameter](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html), and there is also the [`CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO.html#variable:CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO) variable to set a default behaviour:

> `COMMAND_ECHO <where>`
>
> New in version 3.15.
>
> The command being run will be echo'ed to `<where>` with `<where>` being set to one of `STDERR`, `STDOUT` or `NONE`. See the [`CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO.html#variable:CMAKE_EXECUTE_PROCESS_COMMAND_ECHO) variable for a way to control the default behavior when this option is not present.